# Decode a JSON String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, decode

I have a encoded JSON string returning the following sting which I am displaying on my webpage from a database call.

```
{"Value 1":"1234","Value 2":"123456"}
```

How do I decode this string and also format the data to be displayed in a table?

I am at a lost as how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Google the title of the question, and you'll find the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: What you appear to have in your question is already an object, which does not require any decoding.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to create html from json. This post will also be very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to turn a string containing a JSON into an object:

```
JSON.parse('{"Value 1":"1234","Value 2":"123456"}');
```

Comment: Can you parse the JSON string inside a AJAX request?